# How to hide iterators in the API to consume an item in a std::map wrapper

Tags: c++, stl, api-design, stdmap, c++98

In a c++98 project I have a class `Items` that wraps a `std::map`:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Item { /* ... */ }; // Some class holding some data

class Items
{
 public:
    typedef std::map<std::string,Item> container_type;
    typedef container_type::iterator iterator;

    Items() {}

    iterator find(const String& k) { return i_map.find(k); }
    iterator end() { return i_map.end(); }
    void erase(iterator i) { i_map.erase(i); }
    // ...

 private:
    container_type i_map;
};
```

Its main use is to search a certain `Item` and if found use and remove it.
The first obvious API I proposed to *consume* an item was this:

```
Items items;
Items::iterator i = items.find("some-id");
if( i!=items.end() )
   {
    const Item& item = i->second; // Get and use the item
    items.erase(i); // Item consumed: remove it from items
   }
```

...But I was asked to hide the concepts of `iterator` and `pair` from the class API.
To meet this new requirement the first idea was to store internally an iterator `i_found` to remember the last found item:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Item { /* ... */ }; // Some class holding some data

class Items
{
 public:
    typedef std::map<std::string,Item> container_type;
    typedef container_type::iterator iterator;

    Items() : i_found( i_map.end() ) {}

    #define should_be_const // const // Unfortunately 'i_found' must be a non const 'iterator' in order to be erased

    bool contains(const std::string& k) should_be_const
       {
        i_found = i_map.find(k);
        return i_found!=i_map.end();
       }

    const Item& get(const std::string& k) should_be_const
       {
        if(i_found==i_map.end() || k!=i_found->first) i_found = i_map.find(k); // search if necessary
        if(i_found!=i_map.end()) return i_found->second;
        else throw std::runtime_error("key \'" + std::string(k) + "\' not found!");
       }

    void erase_found()
       {
        i_map.erase(i_found);
        i_found = i_map.end(); // invalidate last find
       }

 private:
    container_type i_map;
    mutable iterator i_found; // Last found item
};
```

This gives the possibility to write:

```
Items items;
if( items.contains("some-id") )
   {
    const Item& item = items.get("some-id"); // Get and use the item
    items.erase_found(); // Item used: remove it from items
   }
```

I know that if this is an improvement or not is debatable, I'm not asking about that (yeah, I don't like it either).
Is there a way in this last implementation to make the methods `contains()` and `get()` `const`?

Given the requirement above, I was also interested in suggestions about different approaches.
While `Item` copy construction is acceptable, I'd like to to avoid to construct an `item` if "some-id" was not found, as in this alternative I was desperately trying:

```
bool Items::extract_if_present(const std::string& k, Item& item)
   {
    iterator i = i_map.find(k);
    if( i != i_map.end() )
       {
        item = i->second;
        i_map.erase(i);
        return true;
       }
    return false;
   }

Item item; // <-- Avoidable useless work if not found
if( items.extract_if_present("some-id", item) )
   {
    //item; // Use the copied item
   }
```

Comment: `const_cast` `i_map` to be able to use `const`?

Comment: @Jarod42 They tought me that `const_cast` inside a `const` method is a broken promise, but yes, in this case would be just a *breakable* promise

Comment: `i_map.find` by itself doesn't mutate, so that part doesn't break promise directly (it is more the `mutable` field).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, the quirk is that it's not possible to `erase` a `const_iterator`. I'm aware that this constraint is debatable (accessing an object as immutable is not the same thing as removing an immutable object from the container)

Comment: [`map::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) has been fixed in C++17 to accept `iterator` in addition to `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `optional`(not std, which is C++17, but could be done in C++98 (using `boost` for example)), then you might have in interface

```
optional<Item> get(const std::string&) const;
optional<Item> extract(const std::string&);
```

With usage similar to:

```
Items items;
// ...
if (optional<Item> item = items.extract("some-id"))
{
    // use *item;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad to see confirmed the need I felt for `std::optional`. Unfortunately at this time I'm stuck with an old unsupported compiler (Borland C++ 5.5.1) so I would have to pick an old version of boost, as long as I obtain the authorization to include that big library in the project. I'll search again for alternative implementations.

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a raw pointer for `get`. You can write your own `optional` fairly easily, it's a class with a `bool` and a `char[sizeof(Item)]`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are throwing if the key is not found, you can have a simpler interface than `map`.

```
class Items
{
 public:
    // do these need to be public?
    typedef std::map<std::string, Item> container_type;
    typedef container_type::iterator iterator;

    bool contains(const std::string& k) const
       {
        return i_map.find(k)!=i_map.end();
       }

    const Item& get(const std::string& k) const
       {
        iterator i_found = i_map.find(k);
        if(i_found!=i_map.end()) return i_found->second;
        else throw std::runtime_error("key \'" + k + "\' not found!");
       }

    Item extract(const std::string& k)
       {
        iterator i_found = i_map.find(k);
        if(i_found!=i_map.end()) 
           {
            Item temp = i_found->second;
            map.erase(i_found);
            return temp;
           }
        else throw std::runtime_error("key \'" + k + "\' not found!");
       }

 private:
    container_type i_map;
};
```

If you move to C++11, extract can move instead of copy.

Comment: Calling `contains` before `extract` means calling `find` twice, right? Unless using `extract` in a `try{}catch{}`, but that would involve exceptions in the normal execution flow, not advisable. BTW, one day I will be able to use `auto` too, after porting my projects to a newer developing environment ;-)